# Некорректно отображаются цифры в строке

Tags: css, html5

Верстаю блок имитирующий страницу с кодом. Не получается адекватно пронумировать строки, цифры со значением больше 9 начинают пододвигать соседние блоки вправо.
На скрине ниже пример того как должно быть, и то что получается у меня.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше решить данную проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

HTML

```
 <div class="practite2__question2">
            <div class="practite2__question2-title">
              Вопрос 2
            </div>
            <p class="practite2__question2-text">
              Что выведет в консоли следующий код:
            </p>

            <div class="practite2__question2-task">

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">1</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">using</span> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;</span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">2</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">using</span> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;</span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">3</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">using</span> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">4</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">using</span> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">5</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">using</span> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">6</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red"></span> </span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">7</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">namespace</span> CacheExamples</span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">8</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">
                    </span> </span>
                </div>
                {
              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">9</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red">public class</span> Startup</span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="practite2__question2-block">
                <div class="practite2__num2">10</div>


                <div class="practite2__num2-text2">
                  <span> <span class="practite2__num2-red"></span> {
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>


            </div>


          </div>
```

CSS

```
.practite2__block-text{
  color: rgba(96, 98, 104, 1);
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.practite2__block-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  max-width: 735px;
}

.practite2__block-main{
  display: flex;
}

.practite2__block-title-count{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 96px;
  color: rgba(196, 202, 207, 1);
  position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
}

.practite2__question1-title,
.practite2__question2-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-text,
.practite2__question2-text{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.practite2__question1-task{
max-width: 915px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: rgba(247, 248, 250, 1);
}

.practite2__num,
.practite2__num2{
  font-family: 'Consolas';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(160, 161, 166, 1);
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(117, 182, 135, 1);
}

.practite2__num-text,
.practite2__num2-text2{
    font-family: 'Consolas';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.practite2__question1-block,
.practite2__question2-block{
  display: flex;
}


.practite2__num2-red,
.practite2__question1-red{
  color: rgba(227, 111, 89, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-blue {
  color: rgba(0, 163, 255, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-answer{
  padding: 17px 20px 25px;
  max-width: 915px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.practite2__question1-anwser-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.practite2__question1-answer-text{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  max-width: 875px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
}
```

https://codepen.io/Den323/pen/gOeQYLr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.practite2__block-text{
  color: rgba(96, 98, 104, 1);
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.practite2__block-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  max-width: 735px;
}

.practite2__block-main{
  display: flex;
}

.practite2__block-title-count{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 96px;
  color: rgba(196, 202, 207, 1);
  position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
}

.practite2__question1-title,
.practite2__question2-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-text,
.practite2__question2-text{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.practite2__question1-task{
max-width: 915px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: rgba(247, 248, 250, 1);
}

.practite2__num,
.practite2__num2{
  font-family: 'Consolas';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(160, 161, 166, 1);
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(117, 182, 135, 1);
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.practite2__num-text,
.practite2__num2-text2{
    font-family: 'Consolas';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
    padding-left: 35px;
} 

.practite2__num-text::after,
.practite2__num2-text2::after{
  content: ' ';
}

.practite2__question1-block,
.practite2__question2-block{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}


.practite2__num2-red,
.practite2__question1-red{
  color: rgba(227, 111, 89, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-blue {
  color: rgba(0, 163, 255, 1);
}

.practite2__question1-answer{
  padding: 17px 20px 25px;
  max-width: 915px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.practite2__question1-anwser-title{
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: rgba(35, 38, 45, 1);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.practite2__question1-answer-text{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  max-width: 875px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(226, 231, 235, 1);
}
```

Можно позиционировать абсолютно и сместить влево, а можно задать фиксированную ширину, например. 25-30px

Comment: фиксированная ширина мне не помогла. 
с позиционированием лучше, однако приложив ваш css к html, выходят некоторые ошибки, по типу наезда одной цифры на другую))
https://codepen.io/Den323/pen/gOeQYLr
еще поковыряюсь, может чего-то не разобрал)

Comment: а, не, теперь порядок. ширина как раз и помогла, спасибо за наводку вам!)